# Azure Devops - create pipeline environment with Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

Is there a way to create environments inside the Azure Devops Pipeline using Terraform?
Or is there any other way to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can automate** the creation of an ADO pipeline environment with the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0.).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

On **terraform**, you can find all the terraform resources of Azure Devops provider, [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs). For the moment, it is not possible to create target environments of Azure Pipelines.